# Is putting the theme for an R Quarto document best done by placing css file in a package? If so how?

Tags: css, yaml, themes, quarto

I'm creating some reports using R Quarto and have created a theme (my_theme.css) which I would like my team members to use to make sure that our reports follow the same look and feel.  We have an R package that we use for internal use only and I would like to add my newly developed theme to it.  Could someone explain to me how to do this or give me a reference where I can look it up myself.  Have struggled with this today; any help welcome.

The code in my_theme.css looks like this:

```
/*-- scss:defaults --*/
$font-size-root:        11px !default;
$font-family-sans-serif: "Arial"; /* "Comic Sans MS"; */
$headings-font-style:   bold !default; /* italic, regular, bold */
$h1-font-size:          36px !default; /* h1 refers to the title of the document */
$h2-font-size:          16px !default; /* h2 refers to the header use # */
$h3-font-size:          11px !default; /* h3 refers to the sub-header use ## */
/* This is main text colour.  It applies to body text and all headers. */
$body-color: #574759;
```

and I call the theme from the _quarto.yml file which looks like

```
book:
  title: "My title"
  author: "My name"
  date: today
  date-format: DD MMMM YYYY
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - intro.qmd
    - file1.qmd
    - file2.qmd

bibliography: references.bib

format:
  html:
    theme:
      - cosmo
      - mytheme.scss
```

In summary I would like to put my_theme.css into an R package so that it can be used by other team members internally but unsure how to go about this.  Could anyone help?

Thank you.  Phil,

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code/files?